# Analytics is enabled but not working after upgradation site from Kentico 9 to 10

Tags: kentico

I have upgraded site from Kentico 9 to Kentico 10. I have enabled web analytics in setting but whenever I see report of pages, there is not showing tracking and activity.
Graph is showing only one line on x-axis that means proper report is not generating.I have already done necessary settings and given permissions but it is not reflecting. Please help how can fix it?

Comment: Can you check event log?

Comment: Does your Kentico 10 license allow for Analytics? Web analytics are available in Ultimate and EMS licenses only

Comment: Can you check to see if this folder \CMS\App_Data\CMSModules\WebAnalytics contains files? If there is no file, it means analytics service is not logging data. If there are files here, but nothing in the database, then it's the data processing service not working.

Comment: Thanks to all for valuable suggestions. Due to problem of permissions it was not working. Now it is working.